# Wordpress mu domain mapping

Tags: domain-mapping

I've asked this question on the plugin support page but can't get an answer :/

Is it possible to use the domain mapping plugin to map domains in Wordpress (multisite) that are mapped to domains with a subdirectory?

I can get foo.example.com to map fine, but I can't get example.com/foo to map from blogs.mywebsite.com/bar I get a redirect back to the the route of the site blogs.mywebsite.com.

I'm using the latest wordpress and the latest install of the wordpress domain mapping plugin.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no. If you look at how that plugin stores its mappings:

```
mysql> desc wp_domain_mapping;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| blog_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| domain  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active  | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There simply is not a place to put a path.